# Getting "too many Arguments" With 'IF' function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got some experience with excel and I've been working on this formula for a while now trying to get it to calculate correctly, but I've been unsuccessful. I read that previous questions regarding a similar issue but was still unable to solve my problem.

The function I've created is: =IF(A13<=B5,A13*D5,IF(A13<=B6, (A13-A6)*D6),IF(A13<=B7, (A13-A7)*D7))
I've been trying to fix this for hours now and had no issues with the formula at all when it was just:
=IF(A13<=B5,A13*D5,IF(A13<=B6, (A13-A6)*D6))

I still have more to add, so any feedback regarding methods to prevent this from happening in the future would be great thanks.

Comment: you have a `)` out of place: `=IF(A13<=B5,A13*D5,IF(A13<=B6, (A13-A6)*D6,IF(A13<=B7, (A13-A7)*D7)))`

Comment: and my guess, without seeing the actual data, is that you can simplify the formula with VLOOKUP: `=(A13-VLOOKUP(A13,A5:A7,1))*VLOOKUP(A13,A5:D7,4)`

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake,

One too many parenthesis, corrected version
=IF(A13<=B5,A13*D5,IF(A13<=B6, (A13-A6)*D6,IF(A13<=B7, (A13-A7)*D7)))